# Getting objects to move back and forth in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've recently started learning c# and unity and we're supposed to make a game where a ball rolls around a maze, is in danger of being destroyed by an enemy, and a message pops up when you reach the end. I have most of this done; however, my enemies, who are supposed to move back and forth and destroy the ball when touched, don't work. The walls and floor explodes out when the game is started and I'm not even sure they work at all. In our current assignment, we have to add classes and add another player (which I'm pretty sure I know how to do already). Here's my current code for my enemy class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary
{ 
    public float xMin, xMax;
}

public class BadGuyMovement : MonoBehaviour


{
    public Transform transformx;
    private Vector3 xAxis;
    private float secondsForOneLength = 1f;
    public Boundary boundary;

    void Start()
    {
        xAxis = Boundary;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 3), xAxis);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Player)
    {
        Destroy(Player.gameObject);
    }
}
```

On lines 21 (xAxis = Boundary;) and 26 (transform.position = new Vector 3) there are errors that I just completely don't understand. If you guys know how to fix it or know of a better way to do something, or at least a better way to move an object back and forth, please let me know!

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this!

Comment: xAxis is a Vector3 while Boundary is not, so you should not assign `xAxis = Boundary;`

Comment: I suggest you complete this tutorial successfully first, then you can add your new logic of movable enemies: [tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial)

Comment: I did the roll a ball tutorial already, but the squares are the ones that are moving back and forth in a fixed manner. I tried ping pong, but that only partially helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting errors for two reasons, but fairly trivial.

The first error, on line 21 `(xAxis = Boundary)`, you're getting an error because you're assigning a value of **type** `Boundary` to a variable of **type** `Vector3`.

This is like trying to say an Apple equals an Orange (they don't).

In languages like C#, the types of both the left hand and the right hand of an assignment must be the same.

Simply put

***type*** **variable** = **value**; --> Works only if ***type*** from the LHS = ***type*** from the RHS

Your second error is happening is because you're trying to create a `Vector3` with the wrong set of values. The process of creating a type is done through calling the `Constructor` of the class you're trying to create.

Now, look at the [Constructor for a Vector3](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-ctor.html). One constructor takes 3 parameters of type `float` and the other takes 2 parameters, again of type `float`.
 
You're trying to call the constructor of a `Vector3` using a `float` (from Mathf.PingPong) and a `Vector3` (xAxis).

Now that we have that out of the way, try this code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary
{ 
    public float xMin, xMax;
}

public class BadGuyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform transformx;
    private Vector3 xAxis;
    private float secondsForOneLength = 1f;
    public Boundary boundary;  //Assuming that you're assigning this value in the inspector

    void Start()
    {
        //xAxis = Boundary;  //This won't work. Apples != Oranges.

    }

    void Update()
    {
        //transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 3), xAxis);  //Won't work, incorrect constructor for a Vector3
        //The correct constructor will take either 2 float (x & y), or 3 floats (x, y & z). Let's ping pong the guy along the X-axis, i.e. change the value of X, and keep the values of Y & Z constant.            
        transform.position = new Vector3( Mathf.PingPong(boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), transform.position.y, transform.position.z ); 
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Player)
    {
        Destroy(Player.gameObject);
    }
}
```